# С++ Ошибка компилятора. Множественное определение

Tags: c++

В заголовочном файле создаю объект.
Далее этот заголовочный файл также подключается в другой заголовочный (там также используется этот созданный объект).

Подключаю два сделанных мной заголовочных файлов в main и компилирую. ОШИБКА.
Не понимаю как правильно определить этот создаваемый объект в первом заголовочном файле...

```
#pragma once
#ifndef MQTTCLIENT_H
#define MQTTCLIENT_H
#include <iostream>



extern const char* mqtt_server;
extern char buffer[10];

WiFiClient espClient;            
PubSubClient client(espClient); -> ВОТ ЭТОТ ОБЪЕКТ
```

Comment: Вы в курсе что в хидерах нельзя создавать не константные объекты?

Comment: Неа))) Начинающий... теперь понятно....

Comment: Ну или они должны быть синглтонами (17-й стандарт, inline)

Comment: И используйте что-то одно: либо pragma, либо ifdef - использование обоих не имеет смысла

Comment: да это я оставил, т.к. варианты пробовал))